# Microsoft SQL Server Bulk Insert NOT failing when inserting bigint values into int column

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

We recently had an identifier column move from int values to bigint values.  An ETL process which loads these values was not updated.  That process is using SQL bulk insert, and we are seeing incorrect values in the destination table.  I would have expected a hard failure.

Please note this process has been running successfully for a long time before this issue.

Can anyone tell me what the heck SQL Server is doing here!?  I know how to fix the situation, but I'm trying to better understand it for the data cleanup effort that I'll need to complete, as well as just for the fact that it looks like black magic!

I've been able to re-create this issue in SQL Server 2017 and 2019.

#### Simplified Example CSV file contents:

```
310067463717
310067463718
310067463719
```

#### Example SQL:

```
create table #t (t int)

bulk insert #t from 'c:\temp\test.csv'
with (datafiletype = 'char',
fieldterminator = '|' 
)

select * from #t
```

#### Resulting data:

```
829818405
829818406
829818407
```

Interestingly, I tried with smaller values, and I do see an error:

Example CSV file contents (2147483647 is the largest int value for SQL Server):

```
310067463717
310067463718
310067463719
2147483647
2147483648
```

Running the same SQL code as above, I get an error for one row:

> Msg 4867, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 5, column 1 (t).

The resulting data looks like this:

```
829818405
829818406
829818407
2147483647
```

I also tried just now with a much higher value, 31006746371945654, and that threw the same overflow error as 2147483648.

And last, I did confirm that if I create the table with the column defined as bigint, the data inserted is correct.

```
create table #t (t bigint)

bulk insert #t from 'c:\temp\test.csv'
with (datafiletype = 'char',
fieldterminator = '|' 
)

select * from #t
```

Resulting data:

```
2147483647
2147483648
310067463717
310067463718
310067463719
```

Comment: Have you installed the latest CUs? Did you try SQL Server 2022 too? If this is fixed in SQL Server 2022 there may be a fix in a CU for SQL Server 2019 as well. SQL Server 2017 is out of mainstream support

Comment: Good question, I'm setting up 2022 right now to try there.

Comment: I can replicate this in 2022, @PanagiotisKanavos .

Comment: So, interestingly, the value being displayed is the modulo of 2,147,483,648 (which is the max value of an `int` + 1). So `310067463717` results in `829818405` whu=ich is `310067463717 % 2147483648`

Comment: I must admit, this feels like a bug rather than anything else.

Comment: I just confirmed I'm on the most recent CU of 2019, and I was also able to replicate on 2022.

Comment: And thank you @Larnu! I was trying to figure out the math that was happening but I wasn't able to get there.  That might be really helpful for me in fixing the data!